# Removing Outliers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried removing outliers using the following function I created, but I am getting weird values after using it. Is my way of removing outliers correct?

```
def remove_outliers(df,numeric_features):
'''
remove_outliers is a function which removes outliers by removing any
point above the mean by 2 standard deviations or below the mean by 2 standard deviations
df is the dataframe which the outliers are to be removed from
numeric_features are the numeric columns which might contain outliers
return new data frame
'''

#Iterate all the columns in numeric features
for col in numeric_features:

    mean = df[col].mean() #Find mean of column
    std = np.std(df[col],axis = 0)#find standard deviation of column

    #Variables used to find outliers
    above_outliers = mean + 2*std
    below_outliers = mean - 2*std

    outlier_indexes = df[col].loc[lambda x: (x>=above_outliers)|(x<=below_outliers)]

    #drop outliers from the dataframe column
    df= df.drop(outlier_indexes.index)
return df
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
  df1=  df[(df['col']>=below_outliers)&(df['col']<=above_outliers))
```

Comment: Was my old way of doing it incorrect, because now 110 more rows were deleted but I'm still getting absurd results on the remaining data. Basically, I'm completing the Titanic Classification Kaggle challenge which requires me to predict if a passenger will survive or not on unseen data. When I remove outliers the survival rate of a person with the title Master in front of his name increases to 1 which I do not believe to be true.

Comment: @HashimAbuSharkh could you check alter the condition df[(df['col']>= above_outliers )&(df['col']<=below_outliers))